# Q_LIKELY и Q_UNLIKELY как помощь компилятору в оптимизации кода

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

В справочном примере для макроса `Q_LIKELY` указан цикл и рассматривается ситуация, когда состояние `false` может возникнуть, как говорится, в одном случае на миллион:

```
// the condition inside the "if" will be successful most of the times
for(int i = 1; i <= 365; i++) {
    if(Q_LIKELY(isWorkingDay(i))) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

В целом, эту пользу можно увидеть, учитывая не редкость ситуаций, когда в цикле проверяется значение, подразумевающее нахождение лишь в одном из двух состояний, и при этом одно из них практически всегда будет в подавляющем большинстве случаев.

Но сбивает с толку пример для `Q_UNLIKELY`, хотя и являющийся, судя по наименованию, всего лишь обратным вариантом:

```
bool readConfiguration(const QFile &file) {
    // We expect to be asked to read an existing file
    if(Q_UNLIKELY(!file.exists())) {
        qWarning() << "File not found";
        return false;
    }

    ...
    return true;
}
```

Какая тут может быть "помощь компилятору" в оптимизации кода, и если она всё-таки имеет место быть, то будет ли справедлива и для `Q_LIKELY`? Может быть существуют какие-либо критерии для определения характерных ситуаций, в которых использовании обозначенных макросов имеет смысл?

Comment: Грубо говоря, Q_LIKELY использовать когда редко случается false, Q_UNLIKELY - когда редко случается true. Это помогает компилятору строить более быстрый код.

Comment: Идея этого Q_LIKELY не очень новая. Вот тут можно прочитать, в чём суть: https://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/LikelyUnlikely

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>*В тексте ответа представлено моё субъективное мнение*</sub>

Я считаю что эти макросы бесполезны в 99.99% случаев и должны применятся лишь после измерений, которые показали, что их использование оправдано. Почему? Потому что то, что сегодня «likely», может стать «unlikely» завтра, а программисты очень часто забывают менять вещи, которое явно не отражаются на программе. Таким образом, у нас может быть какая-то проверка помечена как `Q_LIKELY`, тогда как на самом деле всё наоборот. И это будет сбивать с толку программиста, который в дальнейшем будет это читать.

«Но как же так, это же оптимизация?!» — довольно спорное заявление, на самом деле, т.к. *предсказатели ветвления*(branch predictors) в CPU очень хороши, и чем тут **реально** сможет помочь компилятор непонятно. Вот возьмём цикл из вопроса, после первой же итерации, наиболее вероятно, что CPU начнёт выбирать инструкции по той ветке, что была в первой итерации. Что нам даст явное указание, *потенциальный* выигрыш в первой итерации? Смехотворно.

Всё это настолько нанооптимизации, что, повторюсь, прибегать к ним стоит лишь по нахождении проблемы с ветвлением, но не раньше. Программисты, помимо плохой памяти, ещё и не очень хороши в определении того, что же будет чаще(likely) исполняться.

Comment: Добавлю: такая нанооптимизация имеет смысл лишь внутри часто (скажем, миллион раз в секунду) выполняемого цикла, там где точность предиктора крайне важна. Советы предиктору рядом с файловой операцией выглядят смехотворно, наподобие экономии на салфетках при запуске космической ракеты.

Comment: @VladD, а как это поможет миллиону операций? CPU сам там справится неплохо.

Comment: Ну, например, если проверка «в обратную сторону» выполняется на одну инструкцию быстрее в типичном случае, то подсказка компилятору имеет смысл, чтобы он выбрал более эффективную из двух реализаций. (Я не знаю, есть ли ещё хинт для самого _процессора_.)

Comment: @VladD, просто «типичный случай» будет как раз «предсказан» CPU и он начнёт выбирать соответствующие инструкции самостоятельно — ему не нужна подсказка(если только это не первая итерация, в ней, возможно, она была бы полезна). Branch predictor, насколько мне известно, это один из самых секретных модулей в ЦПУ, тайны которого очень хорошо хранятся, потому что он даёт конкурентное преимущество — это очень умная и сложная штука, помощь которой, в общем случае, не нужна.

Comment: Ну, это если предиктор умный и не ошибается. А вдруг он где-то тупит? Например, вначале идёт 1000 «нет», предиктор настраивается, а потом миллионы «да», а предиктор не может динамически подстроиться? Ну и не сбрасывайте со счетов архитектуры попроще, у которых предиктор не такой хороший, как у Intel.